# Making signalr generated proxy hubs url dynamic

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a solution which need to connect using CORS to a signalr exposed service.
The address where the signalr service will be hosted could change in time, so it's not 
suitable to have the classic script tag

```
<script src="http://server:8888/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it would be fantastic if there's a way to reference the above url dynamically by javascript without the static script tag.
Suggestions would be great!

Comment: Why not make the script tag less static: `<script src="<%= SignalRUrl %>...`?

Comment: Sure it can be possible but is not a so elegant and cleaner way to it..now i'm doing that registering a clientscriptreference in the page ScriptManager, but I'd like too much if that's could be accomplished by javascript, so the scripting part is not so coupled with the code-behind one!

Answer (score 4):

Do the following in your JS file:

```
$.getScript('http://server:8888/signalr/hubs', function () {
    //Set the hubs URL for the connection
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://server:8888/signalr';
    var hub = $.connection.yourHub; //yourHub is name of hub on the server side

    //wire up SignalR

    //start hub
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        //once we're done with SignalR init we can wire up our other stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: How do i make this line dynamic "var hub = $.connection.yourHub;" I have a drop down and the hub changes on that drop down selection, so my 'yourHub' needs to be be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your settings in a config file:

**config.json**:

```
{
    "signalr_url": "http://server:8888/signalr"
}
```

Then load the config:

```
$.getJSON('config.json', function(config) {
    $.getScript(config.signalr_url, function() {
        // when the script has loaded
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

After looking at [the SignalR documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client#cross-domain-support), I think the following would be more suitable.

First include the needed scripts:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now you can just call `$.connection(...);` with any url. So applying the above it could look like this:

```
$.getJSON('config.json', function(config) {
    $.connection(config.signalr_url);
});
```

Comment: I haven't tried yet, at first look it seems will work but I cannot say without a try. Just a thing, why in the config .json example you put not the address which ends up with /hubs and instead you used the signalr endpoint address?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same scenario and after some researchs we've decided to put the generated proxy as a physical script like bellow:

> How to create a physical file for the SignalR generated proxy
>
> As an alternative to the dynamically generated proxy, you can create a
>   physical file that has the proxy code and reference that file. You
>   might want to do that for control over caching or bundling behavior,
>   or to get IntelliSense when you are coding calls to server methods.
>
> To create a proxy file, perform the following steps:
>
> Install the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils NuGet package.
>
> Open a command prompt and browse to the tools folder that contains the
>   SignalR.exe file. The tools folder is at the following location:
>
> [your solution
>   folder]\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils.2.1.0\tools
>
> Enter the following command:
>
> signalr ghp /path:[path to the .dll that contains your Hub class]
>
> The path to your .dll is typically the bin folder in your project
>   folder.
>
> This command creates a file named server.js in the same folder as
>   signalr.exe.
>
> Put the server.js file in an appropriate folder in your project,
>   rename it as appropriate for your application, and add a reference to
>   it in place of the "signalr/hubs" reference.

link: [How to create a physical file for the SignalR generated proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy)

As long we have proxy then you can just refer to the Hub url like this:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://your-url/signalr;
//open connection
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        //do your stuff
    })
    .fail(function () { alert('unable to connect'); });
```